# How send test cases into method in ordered format?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

Suppose I have a unit test method called 'Add', in 'Add' method I need to execute some condition of switch case in ordered format for example 1, 2, 3, but 'InlineData' attribute send randomly value inside of unit test method.

Can any one help me?

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(2)]
[InlineData(3)]
public void Add(int value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case 1:{
           //condition one
           ...
         break;
       }
       case 2:{
          //condition two
           ...
         break;
       }
       case 3:{
           //condition three
           ...
         break;
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "Randomly"? Do you mean you need it in the exact order 1,2,3?

Comment: why do you care for the order of your tests?

Comment: Write your test in such a way that order doesn't matter, or conversely, if your implementation requires a specific order, then you need to write your test explicitly with that order, to make clear that the order is important.

Comment: Test cases must be fully independent of each other.

Comment: Unit Testing must be independent of the order that it executes, currently there is no way you order the sequence of execution of InlineData. If at all you need them in order, better pass new int[] in InlineData

Comment: Hi  @MakePeaceGreatAgain, yes in need in order of 1 ,2 3

Comment: Hi @Alexander Petrov, i can't separate my condition, They are depend on each other.

Comment: While there are a few best practice suggestions here that should be followed, to say that it cannot be done is wrong. See: `ITestCollectionOrderer`

https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/08/16/xunit-control-the-test-execution-order/

Comment: If they are dependent on each other to be executed in the correct order, then it is a single test case and not 3. You can write a for loop for in that case.

Comment: Is it possible that you give a bit more context around your use case? It seems more like you’ve got flawed business logic or flawed thinking in how to test this

Answer (score 0):

you can write you own codes in one unit of block and then control of dependencies and the order of your conditions.
For example below code block may help you.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(2)]
[InlineData(3)]
public void Add(int value)
{
   
       //condition one
       var result_one = method1();
       Xunit.Assert.NotNull(result_one);
     
    
       //condition two
       var result_two = method2(result_one);
       Xunit.Assert.NotNull(result_two);
     
       // condition three
       var result_three = method3(result_two );
       Xunit.Assert.NotNull(result_three);
    

}
```

Comment: I’d argue that by doing this then your test is too complicated. It’s doing too many things